# undo this terminal command:

Tags: 12.04, shutdown

I wanted to disable my power button in ubuntu 12.04, so I ran

```
    gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power nothing
```

that worked fine, but now I want to re-enable my power button. what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the terminal run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power interactive
```

You can also directly edit this configuration setting as well as your entire configuration database in Ubuntu 12.04 using a GUI application called Configuration Editor which is from the *dconf-tools* package in the Ubuntu Software Center.